# force close when clicking the back button in android phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, back-button

I have created android phonegap app using html,css,javascript and
    jquery.When i hit the back button my app gets force closed.My error in
    the logcat is below:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(23383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(23383): android.view.WindowManager
    $BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token
    android.os.BinderProxy@48c59828 is not valid; is your activity
    running?
    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:505)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:207)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:121)
    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:259)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
    at com.phonegap.DroidGap$GapClient.onJsAlert(DroidGap.java:983)
    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:531)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit
    $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    ERROR/(1364): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Please kindly guide me where i am wrong.Thanks in advance.

Comment: cant help you with this information, will you please share some more of your code of the page where you get force close. there's an event provided by phonegap/cordova that fires on back button press. have you checked it.

Comment: what is your code on backpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the activity is finishing before showing that dialog.

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
    showDialog(MY_DIALOG);
}
```

The crash occurs when a background thread tries to show a dialog just when the UI thread is exiting.

Comment: I got the problem when the dialog is already opened - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886569/the-app-crashes-unable-to-add-window-token-android-os-binderproxy-is-not-val

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> android.os.BinderProxy@48c59828 is not valid; is your activity
> running?
> ```

This error mostly occurs when you are trying to `close/finish` the Activity when some `ProgressDialog` is running. So, you are trying to `finish()` Activity before dismissing Progress Dialog. You should first try to dismiss the ProgressDialog then finish the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

$BadTokenException:

this type of error because of context problem.
pass proper context in your code,