# The app crashes: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins

We have build a Cordova app with the `org.apache.cordova.dialogs` plugin installed and JQM.

After start (onDeviceReady) we show the dialog using `navigator.notification.alert`.

Then we press `HOME` button to return to the home screen and after this we get the following error:

> 06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity mobi.appcoins.AppCoins has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{16e65b66 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,437} that was originally added here
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:993)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification.changeTextDirection(Notification.java:477)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification.access$1(Notification.java:474)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification$2.run(Notification.java:182)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   06-17 13:39:22.735: E/WindowManager(498):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Show you relevat code or create a working plnkr so we can debug.

Comment: 1. Create Cordova Android app - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html
2. Add >navigator.notification.alert line to onDeviceReady listener
3. Run the app, see the dialog, press HOME button, check the logs